# Flask - For loop not returning the same output as I want it to

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm having issues with my flask code, it won't simply return the same structure I want it to

Here's my code for starters:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
from lxml import html
import urlopen, urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
#tv
    tvPage = requests.get("https://www.freeview.co.uk")
    tvSoup = BeautifulSoup(tvPage.content)
    tvData = tvSoup.find_all("div",{"class": "box__listing"})
    tvList = []
    for program in tvData:
        tvList = tvList + [program]
    tvNews = tvList


    return render_template("main.html", tvNews=tvNews)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,port=6500)
```

And in the html template I got the following:

```
{% for program in tvNews %}
    <li>{{ program.text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

This returns the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfxo8.jpg

My question is: How can I make it so each new timeslot is on a new row? Right now it treats the 9pm and 10pm as one string, and not the way Freeview displays it (see screenshot)

When I run it in terminal I get it in new rows, and when I inspect the element with chrome dev tools, it looks like they are on all new rows. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you just extract the text from one element you're bound to get everything on one line. The `box__listing` elements have more structure inside them, make use of that.

Comment: I tried getting the "dl" element, but that just returns the same structure. Could you maybe point me in the right direction on this? Here's the website I'm parsing: https://www.freeview.co.uk/

Comment: The `dl` element isn't an improvement because one element still contains both lines. Use the `dt` and `dd` elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Alex, now it looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/1lN6o - I guess it's a step in the right direction at least. Now I gotta figure out how to get them on the same line :)

Comment: You'll want to iterate over the `dt` and `dd` elements separately, and perhaps do something like this: `[' '.join(line) for line in zip(the_dts, the_dls)]`

Comment: Thanks Scott, I tried this: 

    tvNews = [" ".join(str(line)) for line in zip(tvData, tvData2)]

 I don't understand why it returns just a blank slate on my website. Interestingly enough

    {% for program in tvNews %} 
        <li>{{ program.text }}</li> 
    {% endfor %} 

Returns nothing, but 

    {% for program in tvNews %}
        <li>{{ program }}</li> 
    {% endfor %} 

Works and returns everything with the tags, <dt> and <dd>

Answer (score 0):

Add `safe` filter to your variable:

```
{{ program.text|safe }}
```